# how to collect release version in lots of git repositories

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have lots of git repositories which are managed by [repo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repo_%28script%29).
I know the "repo start" and "git push" is a solution to record the version of all repositories. 
But I don't want to see lots of branches or tags on all repositories. 
Especially, I want to check all of logs as time sorting even the log is on different git so that I can track every changes easily, and without "git log" one by one.
Are there any tools help me?

==========

After a half day for research …
I find the `repo manifest -r` maybe a solution.
This command outputs a manifest.xml by recording SHA1 of each git repository.
I use this routine:

```
cd .repo/manifests
repo manifest -r -o default2.xml
cp default2.xml default.xml
git commit -am "Release manifest.xml"
```

After committing a repository is done, do this routine once.
Is there better method than this?

=====================================

I draw a diagram to explain my question.

[image: release version in git repositories]

Is there any tool to manage these released versions? I would like switch among release not only a single git.So far, I only find the command repo manifest -r to do this job. What are the key words to find this kinds of requirement?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how `repo` works, but if you are looking for something that runs git commands recursively against a directory containing git repositories - try [`rgit`](http://p3rl.org/rgit)